When I while loop in my owl carosel then my dots and nav are deseble how to active dots and nav?
When I apply while loop in my testimonial section then my dots and nav are disable how to active my dots and nav
<div class="container-fluid testimonial pb-5">
        <div class="container pb-5">
            <div class="text-center mx-auto pb-5 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s" style="max-width: 800px;">
                <p class="text-uppercase text-secondary fs-5 mb-0">Testimonials</p>
                <h2 class="display-4 text-capitalize mb-3">Our clients reviews.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-carousel testimonial-carousel wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">

                <?php  
                $testimonial_query=new WP_query(array(

                    'post_type'     =>'testimonial',
                    'posts_per_page'    =>2,
                ));
                while($testimonial_query->have_posts()):$testimonial_query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="testimonial-item bg-light p-4">
                    <div class="position-relative">
                        <i class="fa fa-quote-right fa-2x text-primary position-absolute" style="bottom: 30px; right: 0;"></i>
                        <div class="mb-4 pb-4 border-bottom border-secondary">
                            <p class="mb-0"><?php the_content()?>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-nowrap">
                            <div class="me-4">
                                <!-- <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri()?>/img/testimonial-1.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt=""> -->
                                <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('full',array('class'=>'img-fluid w-100','style'=>'width: 100px; height: 100px'));?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-block">
                                <h4 class="text-dark"><?php the_title();?></h4>
                                <p class="m-0 pb-3"><?php  the_field('testimonial')?></p>
                                <div class="d-flex text-secondary pe-5">
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star text-muted"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile;?>
                

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

I am totaly confused, how can I solve this issue?
